# Increase horizontal speed scroll on Logitech Mouse

Tags: mouse, settings, macos

I have a Logitech Mouse with a horizontal-scroll-enabled scroll wheel (it tilts left and right to scroll left and right) the only problem is that the scroll speed is very very slow to a point it is not worth using.

The normal mouse settings do not appear to alter the scroll speed at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the Logitech Control Center [here.](http://www.logitech.com/584/3129) It will allow you to change the settings.

Comment: What about shift-scroll? How do you slow that down?

Comment: @Jeeve Slowing shift-scroll down? Are you using a Logitech mouse, or are you talking about just in general?